# Bootstrap responsive is not working from assets folder in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have an Angular 12 setup with bootstrap 4.0.0. I put the bootstrap file in `assets/css` folder. The desktop looks good but the responsive design is not working as expected. Even if I load the file in `styles.css` from the assets folder, it does not work.

Even I have a proper meta tag for responsive CSS.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

Then, if I load the bootstrap file from the npm package or set the CDN link, it works perfectly. I would like to know the reason why it is not working here.

My `package.json` file is

```json
{
  "name": "backpack-housing",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --aot --build-optimizer --base-href /frontend/",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "ng-http-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "ng-select2-component": "^8.0.5",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "swiper": "^7.0.8",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: check your `angular.json` and set your styles like this `"styles": ["./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "src/styles.scss"]`

Comment: @BladimirMedranoVargas Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned in the description, the bootstrap npm package works fine when loaded in the styles array. But if you have the bootstrap file in the "src/assets/css/bootstrap.css" path and you put it in the styles array, it does not work.